# Existence of a solution to ordinary differential equation where Carathéodory's theorem doesn't apply

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Let us consider a simple ode:
$$
\dot{x}(t) = H(x(t)), \quad x(0) = x_0,
$$
where $H(t)$ is the Heaviside function defined to be 
$$
H(t) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } t > 0 \\
0 & \text{if } t \le 0
\end{cases}.
$$
Intuitively, the solution to the ODE should be 
$$
x(t) = \begin{cases}
x_0 & \text{if } x_0 \le 0 \\
x_0 + t & \text{if } x_0 > 0
\end{cases}.
$$
I have two questions:

> 1. How to rigorously solve the above ODE?
> 2. In this case, the Carathéodory's theorem does not apply since the right hand side is not continuous with respect to $x$. Is there any other theorem or a variant of Caratheodory to ensure the existence of the solution of such kinds of ODEs?

It seems that these questions look elementary, however, I couldn't find any satisfactory answers in a couple of textbooks I looked up.

Any suggestions/comments/answers will be very appreciated.